# Android Strange crash with nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash

I have an android app that works fine on 2 or 3 Samsung phones, but the problem is on LG phone. It is strange because the app works fine and suddenly restart, white screen and start again, sometimes throws

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2308)
       at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
       at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1108)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1956)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1152)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1334)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1039)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I don't know what is null because i can't get from the exception print where the problem starts. It is too generic. Also It is strange that only on the LG phone happens and It is stable on Samsung phones.

Comment: can you provide us with your code?or tell us what your app is doing or what special things it uses?and Is your Samsung phones API equal to your LG phones API?Your Question is too general.you have to provide more details.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, of course i can give you code, the thing is that i don't know where is happening the problem, like i said the exception is really too general, so i don't know what code to show you, what i do on the app is to call my webservice bring data and populate recycleviews, i check the webservice always have a response and catch when not. I have Appcompatactivitys and Fragments where i set the adapters is on the Fragments. Also another data is that the app works fine nothing is wrong not crash when you tap, crash when you stop tapping like you put the phone on the table.

Comment: is there more of this exception's stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

One way to debug this sort of issues is to run app in the debug mode with setting `Java Exception Breakpoints`. You can access it in `Run` - `View Breakpoints...`. then check `Java Exception Breakpoints` and check `Any Exception`. This setting will break the flow whenever an exception will be thrown so you can get better idea of the state of your system by examining values of different `ListView`'s you have used in your system.

About your specific crash, I would pay attention to different `Context`'s objects while debugging (Just an opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your arraylist or list to bind with your adapter for list. As like 
`ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`